# How to ensure the name of the output of my function is related to my input?

Tags: r

I wrote a simple function, but I don't know how I can assign unique name to the output that is returned from this function based on input.

Also, I am using `<<-` to get the desired output from the function because it is escaping my mind how to get the output of the function if I use  `train <-` and `test<-` in the code below(side question).

```
train_data <- function(x,ratio=80){
set.seed(397)
index <- 1:length(x)
tr_index<- index[sample(c(T,F), length(x), replace = T, prob = c((ratio)/100,(100-ratio)/100))]

train <<- x[tr_index]
test <<- x[!(index %in% tr_index)]
}
```

I don't want to the output to be overwritten each time, thus if the command is `train_data(a)` I would like `train_a` and `test_a` to appear in my environment.  I am trying to force `paste0()` into this function but don't know how.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reaching outside the function environment with the global assignment operator, just have the function return a list containing the train and test sets. I've also tried to streamline the code:

```
train_data <- function(x, fraction=0.8){
  tr_index = sample(1:nrow(x), floor(nrow(x) * fraction)))
  return(list(train=x[tr_index, ], test=x[-tr_index, ]))
}
```

Then, when you run the function, you can assign the result to whatever you want. For example:

```
mtcars_split = train_data(mtcars)
```

For a vector, the function would be:

```
train_data <- function(x, fraction=0.8){
  tr_index = sample(1:length(x), floor(length(x) * fraction)))
  return(list(train=x[tr_index], test=x[-tr_index]))
}
```

And you can of course also generalize the function to handle either vector or data frame input.

Comment: That is helpful very helpful.  I see the `[-index]`.    I can extract the vectors from the list. I did forget to mention in the post, that I am sampling from a large character vector hence `[index]`.  Thanks